# Can I prevent deletion of a specific RSA key?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I am making a Windows Service which at certain points in its execution requires logging into a server using a username and password so I have been faced with the security issue of where to store these login details.

Initially I was going to use the Windows Credential Manager, but due to the user access of Windows Services (I need to use the Local System account) it was not the best option. I have settled on storing an encryption key by using an `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, like so:

```
using rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(new CspParameters
{
    Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore,
    KeyContainerName = "UniqueKeyId"
});
```

which I can later use to decrypt the usernames and passwords I store in their encrypted, base64 forms, like so:

```
"MyLoginInfo":
{
    "Username" : "LettWH4VMbvEG/OUBXGLluyceEG8Gon1fOytQ0IoKys18KSCfz6lc8fVO6XxBJtnSzjR23OAoE9TxG9lIqSRdpDwGGaTLGa3bpTGxzKlq+3OoLRo4Hf+9VEn/GO/UEZnzAmalPLErQO87krPmJuWCDqTthtPmi2Kh9jbcavz7Ss=",
    "Password" : "Pnq3KoPip2WHpnDQivc8b0VOMzFn0W/OtSIVSELSE8SNqJSiRHa/6Yt47ndpyZRe6hTSvz3RZeLxaeQ+X1QIm1VRxESzbgz3ZFFzxy6F2ZJAikygWBhzNnu3jywG6u1C7amN7IO9/dHu2T6Jw8n6U1MTYgN2bV4lmGNHJ2bwAnA="
}
```

So my question is, what is to stop this from being called by some external process:

```
using rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(new CspParameters
{
    Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore,
    KeyContainerName = "UniqueKeyId"
});
rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
rsa.Clear();
```

And my key being eradicated, making decryption impossible at a later time? I'm not sure it would likely ever happen but the possibility is bothersome. Should I make my key container name extremely unique, like a GUID or hash of some kind? No one would be able to "browse" through all the available keys, would they?